# $n!+1$ being a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial, square-numbers

One observes that 
\begin{equation*}
4!+1 =25=5^{2},~5!+1=121=11^{2} 
\end{equation*}
is a perfect square. Similarly for $n=7$ also we see that $n!+1$ is a perfect square. So one can ask the truth of this question:

- Is $n!+1$ a perfect square for infinitely many $n$? If yes, then how to prove.

Comment: I remember having this same question while trying to prove that some polynomials were irreducible in an algebra assignment years ago.  Namely, $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)+1$ is irreducible when $n$ is not $4$.  After showing that its reducibility would imply that it is a square, one is led to your question.  We didn't know it was an open problem.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805068

Comment: The pair $(m, n)$ of the form $$n! + 1 = m^2$$ are called *Brown Numbers*. It has been conjectured that there only exists *three* pairs. You can do a little bit of research.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is Brocard's problem, and it is still open.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem

Comment: oh ho! great i didnt know about it

Comment: Note that the article says that the number of solutions is finite on the assumption that the ABC conjecture is true. There is now a claimed proof of the ABC conjecture.

Comment: According to Wikipedia's [ABC Conjecture entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture), the original proof was in error, but as of March 2013, a proposed correction has been posted.

Answer (score 8):

The sequence of factorials $n!+1$ which are also perfect squares is [here in Sloane](https://oeis.org/A085692). It contains three terms, and notes that there are no more terms below $(10^9)!+1$, but as far as I  know there's no proof.

Answer (score 4):

My intuition would be that there are very few.  There are just not many squares and even fewer factorials.  [OEIS A025494](https://oeis.org/A025494) lists the squares which are a sum of distinct factorials, which is less restrictive than what you ask and says the list is probably finite.  In particular, there are no more below 31!