# Solving $x!+1=y^2 $integer solutions,example：$(4,5),(5,11),(7,71)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, square-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$n!+1$ being a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/n1-being-a-perfect-square)

Solving $$x!+1=y^2$$ integer solutions,

example：$(4,5),(5,11),(7,71)$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/n1-being-a-perfect-square/7940#7940

Comment: You mean $(7, 71)$?

Comment: Do we need to play 20 questions to figure out what your question is? :)

Comment: This question is isomorphic to the question it contains in the sense that it has been recently closed.

Comment: I have given a proof  in :
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892315/179940