# $1+n!=m^{2}$ for some n,m$\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial, square-numbers

I have no idea whether this is known or not and I couldn't find anything related on Google. While I was studying , I come up with this idea $1+n!=m^{2} $ for some $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$

$1+4!=5^{2}$

$1+5!=11^{2}$

$1+?!=?^{2}$

and the question is what is the next number? Wolfram Alpha gave me this interesting graph: [image]

Thanks in advance for your interest.

Comment: How this graph was generated?

Comment: I just wrote $n!=m^{2}-1$ on wolfram alpha and it gave me this graph.

Comment: 1+7! = 71^2 and no further values of m below 1000.

Comment: $4,5,7$ are the only solutions.

Comment: @Lucian how did you decide there are only solutions ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7938

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n!+%3D+m^2-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$4!+1=5^2\\5!+1=11^2\\7!+1=71^2$$

This problem is known as Brocard's Problem, and pairs of integers which satisfy it are known as Brown Numbers. There are no other known solutions up to $10^9!+1$.

Comment: it is amazing to know Brocard's Problem and I am so happy to find out this myself..

Comment: I have given a proof  in :
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892315/179940

Answer (score -2):

$m^2-n!-1=0\Rightarrow m=\pm\sqrt{(n!)^2+1}$ this should help you to find $n$ since you need $(n!)^2+1$ to be a square  I.e. $(n!)^2+1=a^2$ for some $a\in(2k-1)\mathbb{N}$ (odds)

Comment: I don't think this is easy because here $\Gamma(n+1)^{2}+1=a^{2}$ but original questions is $\Gamma(n+1) + 1=m^{2}$. Am I wrong ?