# When does $(p-1)! + 1 = p^k $ hold?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have a prime $p$ and an integer $k > 0$. When does the following equation stand?

$(p-1)! + 1 = p^k $

I have obviously tried for some little numbers, and in some cases, it stands:

For $ p=2$ and $k=1, 1 + 1 = 2$.

For $ p=3$ and $k=1, 2 +1 = 3.$

For $ p=5$ and $k=2, 24 + 1 = 25.$

Any ideas, how to prove, if there are more, and if yes, what are the solutions?

Comment: No, it was actually a bad suggestion, that's why I deleted it. You've already stated the $p$ is prime, and Wilson theorem implies that only prime numbers can be candidates here, so it brings no additional insights.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping though. :)

Comment: Nice question -- I suspect it's too hard to answer in general. Note that $p$ always divides $(p-1)! + 1$ and that no prime less than $p$ divides it. However, the number of primes less than $(p-1)!+1$ grows quadratically in $\log(p)$ whereas the number of primes less than $p$ grows linearly in $\log(p)$, so heuristically I suspect this becomes rarer and rarer as $p$ grows.

Comment: But you can combine the fact implied by Wilson theorem, and the fact that "factorial plus $1$ being square" is still an open problem ([see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/7940/131263)), in order to conclude that your question most likely falls under the same category (i.e., an open problem).

Comment: How come that I get an open problem as homework? :D

Comment: aha, then it's probably not an open problem.

Comment: Hmmmm, good question... Perhaps you can post it as yet another question here :) ... Just kidding, there is probably a better answer than "open problem". But you should really do a little research on when a factorial plus 1 is a perfect square (you can start with the link that I gave you on the previous comment).

Comment: Okay, I will do it, thanks for your effort.

Comment: If this is a homework it means there should be some way to determine it, said that, it doesn't hold for any prime between 6 and 20 so it doesn't seems to have any easy prime clasification, I would try to prove that the answer is that it just holds for $p=2,3,5$ but seems hard.

Comment: @AlexR No, for every prime, $k=1$ is a solution modulo $p$, but not necessarily satisfies the equation. For example for $p=13$, $12!+1 \neq 13$

Comment: @AlexR For $p=7,$ note $(p-1)!+1=7\cdot 103.$ (not a powe of $7$

Comment: @MathGod Sorry, I misread as finding the prime power of $p$.

Comment: I have given a proof for $k=2$  in :
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892315/179940

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315974/solving-a-little-diophantine-equationn-11-nm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We show there cannot be any solutions for $p\gt 5$
$$(p-1)!+1 = p^k \implies (p-1)! = p^k-1 = (p-1)\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}p^i$$

Cancel $p-1$ both sides and get
$$(p-2)! = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}p^i$$

Notice that left hand side is divisible by  $p-1$ for $p\gt 5$ 
$$\begin{align}0&\equiv \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}p^i \pmod{p-1}\\0&\equiv \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}1 \pmod{p-1}\\0&\equiv k \pmod{p-1}\\k&=t(p-1)\end{align}$$

So we need $k$ to be of form $t(p-1)$

$$(p-1)! + 1 = p^{t(p-1)}$$

Clearly this is impossible because $(p-1)! + 1 \lt p\cdot p\cdots (\text{p-1 times}) =   p^{p-1}$

That proves there are no solutions for $p\gt 5$.

Comment: Very nice and simple, thanks!

Comment: Can you spell out why the left hand side is divisible by p−1 for p>5 please?

Comment: n is composite by definition, and therefore its factors must be in (n-1)!?

Comment: The only interesting case is if n is the square of a prime p and p > 2, then 2p is divisible by p and 2p < n, 
so (n-1)! is divisible by p², which is n.

Comment: I have given a proof for $k=2$  in :
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892315/179940

Comment: It should be mentioned that $t>0$ because it's given that $k>0$ or because $(p-1)!>0$. Also, clearly $t\in\mathbb Z$.