# Determine all positive integers $(a,n)$ such that $(a-1)!+1=a^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I’m in trouble with this problem. 
The following is what I have done until now.
First of all $a$ must be prime because if $(a-1)!+1=a^n$ then is true also that $ (a-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{a}$ and so, by Wilson’s theorem $a$ is prime.

$(1,n)$ is not a solution. 
Consider $a\neq1$ and $n=1$: we then have $(a-2)!=1$ and so when $n=1$ the solutions are $(2,1)$ and $(3,1)$.

Consider $n=2$. We then have 
$$
(a-2)!=a+1
$$
$a=5$ is a solution but $a=7$ is not and in particolar $5!>8$ and, due to the rapid explosion of the factorial we do not have other solution when $n=2$.

Consider now $n>2$. We could write by hypothesis
$$
(a-1)!=(a-1)(a-2)!=a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+...+a+1)
$$
By Wilson theorem we could write:
$$
(a-2)!=ak+1
$$
for some integer k and so simplifying:
$$
k=a^{n-2}+...+a+1
$$
Now because $a$ is prime (and $a>3$) it is odd and so if $n$ is even (odd) $k$ is a sum of a odd (even) number of odd addends and so it is odd (even).  If $k$ is even we have that $ak+1$ is odd, but $ak+1=(a-2)!$ and $(a-2)!$ is even, thus we must have $k$ odd and so $n$ must be a even integers.

I do not know if for $n>2$ even there are other solutions, I can’t go further.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: $(1,n)$ is not a solution, because $0!=1$.

Comment: @TonyK yes! I edit

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805068/to-find-all-n-such-that-n-11-is-a-perfect-power-of-n/805202#805202