# Primality of $n! +1$

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial, primality-test

I came across with a problem where I was required to examine primality of $n! +1$ (17! + 1 was the actual number).

Although Wilson's Theorem could be manipulated for determining primality of $n! + 1$ when $n + 1$ is a prime and $n! - 1$ when $n + 2$ is a prime, it does not cover the specific example that I am dealing with. Is there any formula (or a more generalized formula that covers the whole problem space) for determining primality of $n! +1$ when $n + 1$ is not a prime?

Comment: Not an answer, but it seems that the topic is covered under the name [Factorial Prime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialPrime.html)

Comment: It just gives a list of known factorial primes.

Comment: seeing as $17!+1 = 661 \times 537913 \times 1000357$ I'm not sure a similar argument can apply

Comment: How about [the first section here](http://www.qbyte.org/puzzles/p120s.html)

Comment: This is a re-statement of what I said above.

Comment: [OEIS A002981](http://oeis.org/A002981) gives initial values of $n$ of $$0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 27, 37, 41, 73, 77, 116, 154, 320, 340, 399, 427, 872, 1477, 6380, 26951, 110059, 150209$$ of which, thanks to Wilson's theorem, only $1$ and $2$ immediately precede a prime.  It labels the sequence as "hard"

Comment: @Henry So it seems like it is hard to come up with a generic solution. The funny thing is that being a P.E. teacher in Turkey requires solving questions like this.

Comment: Could you explain that statement?

Comment: @Axoren do you mean the P.E. thing?

Comment: Yeah. Physical Education teachers needing Wilson's Theorem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$n!+1$ being a perfect square](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/n1-being-a-perfect-square)