# Determine whether $712! + 1$ is a prime number or not

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $n = 712! + 1$ If $n$ was a prime number then, by Wilson's theorem:

$ (712!)! \equiv -1 \pmod{712}$

The double factorial makes it seriously more difficult...

But We can require:

$$712!! + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{712}$$

$$712 = 2\cdot 356$$

Hence: $712!! = 2^{356} 356!$

Lets compute: $356! \pmod{712}$. Obviously:

$$356! = (356 \cdot 2) \cdot (355!/2)  = 712 \cdot 355!/2$$

Then: $356! \pmod{712} \equiv 0$.

Now, $2^{356} \pmod{712}$

$2^{356} = 2^{6 + 350}$

Nevermind, what should I do?

Comment: The Maple command [isprime](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=isprime) answers "false".

Comment: I think you mixed up $(712!)!$ with $712!!$.

Comment: I don't have a better answer than "Well, you could try trial division" - and it happens that $719$ divides $712!+1$, so trial division is okay in this case. In general, such a method would require lots of luck...

Comment: $(712!)! \equiv -1 \pmod{712}\iff 0\equiv -1\pmod {712}\iff 712\mid 1$ leads to an obvious contradiction, but the first congruence is actually $(712!)! \equiv -1 \pmod{712!+1}$.

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ By [Wilson factorial reflection,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/23810/242)  prime $\, p>7 \ \Rightarrow\  p\,\mid\, 1+(\color{#c00}7\!-\!1)!\,(p-\color{#c00}7)!\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, please do not hate me for this, but you are amazing at number theory. Do you think you can help here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151974/proving-11-1-is-prime ???

Answer (score 10):

Since $719$ is prime, by [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) we have that $$718!\equiv 718\cdot 717\cdot 716\cdot 715\cdot 714\cdot 713\cdot 712!\equiv -1\pmod {719}$$

To prove that $719\mid 712!+1$, it is sufficient to prove that $$\begin{align}718\cdot 717\cdot 716\cdot 715\cdot 714\cdot 713&\equiv 1\pmod {719}\\\iff(-1)\cdot(-2)\cdot(-3)\cdot(-4)\cdot(-5)\cdot(-6)&\equiv 1\pmod {719}\\\iff 6!&\equiv 1\pmod {719}\\\iff 720&\equiv 1\pmod {719}\ \ \ \square
\end{align}$$

Comment: That is fine but you still need to *know* to look at $719$.

Comment: @Ihf To be fair, I saw this at a recent olympiad a few months ago, and the official solution was exactly this. I honestly disagree it is at all difficult to think of this solution. Proving that $n!+1$ is prime for a large enough $n$ is _really_ difficult, and so naturally you would expect an olympiad problem to ask to prove its compositeness. Naturally, $n!+1$ is not easily factorable in any way. The only natural way I can think of to proceed here is to use modular arithmetic to prove that a particular prime divides $712!+1$, and the only reasonable way to do this is Wilson's theorem.

Comment: @Ihf And now that you know it is Wilson's theorem you're going to use and there's no way you can factor anything here, you're going to start by checking primes close to $712$.

Comment: It is $\,k=6\,$ in  [Wilson factorial reflection:](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/23810/242) $ $ prime $\, p>k \ \Rightarrow\  p\,\mid\, (-1)^k\!+k!\,(p\!-\!k\!-\!1)!\ \ $

Comment: Still doesnt make sense. how does this possible help show $712! +1$ is not prime?

Comment: @Lebes I showed that $718\cdot 717\cdot 716\cdot 715\cdot 714\cdot 713\equiv 1\pmod{719}$ and so $718!\equiv 1\cdot 712!\equiv -1\pmod{719}$ (since $719$ is prime and so $718!\equiv -1\pmod{719}$) and thus $712!\equiv -1\pmod{719}\iff 719\mid 712!+1$ and so there's a prime divisor less than $712!+1$.

Answer (score 3):

No, $712!+1$ is not prime, see [here](http://oeis.org/A002981) in integer sequences. Further references are given there. The next factorial prime here is $872!+1$. See also the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994991/primality-of-n-1), and [this article](http://www.utm.edu/~caldwell/preprints/primorials.pdf) by Caldwell and Gallot.

Comment: How do you prove that?

Comment: Not necessarily a proof. But In general how would i determine if $n! + 1$ was prime or not?

Comment: Special primality tests for factorial primes, see [here](http://www.primegrid.com/forum_thread.php?id=1336&nowrap=true), or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994991/primality-of-n-1).

Comment: @Lebes Find some primes $p_1,\ldots,p_k>n$ close to $n$ and then check using Wilson's theorem whether or not they divide $n!+1$. See my answer for an example.