# Can you find it? or Can you prove it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, square-numbers

$x!+1=y^2$, I found 3 solutions. They are $(4,5),(5,11),(7,71)$. Is there a $4$th solution?If not can you prove it?

Comment: Never mind, not a duplicate, since the OP here asks for just one more solution instead of infinitely many.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: I have given a proof  in :
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892315/179940

Answer (score 2):

The same question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/n1-being-a-perfect-square?rq=1). What you have asked is still an open question in Mathematics.

As stated in the wikipedia article [Brocard's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard's_problem),  Overholt (1993) showed that there are only finitely many solutions provided that the abc conjecture is true. There is now under evaluation a proof of the abc conjecture by Shinichi Mochizuki.