# a version of the famous $n!+1=m^2$ problem

Tags: number-theory, factorial, conjectures, square-numbers

It is still unknown if $n!+1=m^2$ has only 3 solutions, i.e. for $n=4,5,7$.

[$n!+1$ being a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/n1-being-a-perfect-square)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem

---

What about my problem:

Are there finitely or infinitely many numbers $n$ such that $n!+1$ is divisible by a perfect square greater than 1?

It is also interesting if $n!+1$ is squarefree for infinitely many $n$.

---

For $n\le 100$, number $n!+1$ is:

- prime for $n=1,2,3,11,27,37,41,73,77$
- perfect square for $n=4,5,7$
- divisible by a square (while not being a perfect square) for $n=12,23$
- composite squarefree for other $n$'s

Comment: Other examples I found so far : $$563^2\mid 562!+1$$ $$613^2\mid 229!+1$$

Comment: If infinite many WIlson primes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_prime) exist which is conjectured the answer to your question is "infinite many n"

Comment: Thanks! Did you factorize $n!+1$ up to $n=562$? Are all others (for $n=101,\dots 561$ except 229 composite squarefree?

Comment: No, with factordb you can look up the factorizations of $n!+1$ upto a quite large limit.

Comment: But for a further example, the prime factor must exceed $10^5$

Comment: I just completed the $10^5$-range

Comment: Unfortunately, determining whether a number is squarefree is to current knowledge not easier in general than factoring. For $n\le 1\ 000$ , for another pair the prime factor must exceed $10^7$

Comment: The first hole in factordb is at $n=140$ , so we cannot be absolutely sure in the case of $140!+1$ until someone factored it

Comment: that's a nice tool (factordb - I didn't knew about this, I was using WolframAlpha, it factorizes up to $100!+1$ and fails to factorize for the first time at $101!+1$)

Comment: Then, I assume Wolfram Alpha knows the factors because within the time-limit there, the factorization would probably not be completed for all $n$ upto $100$

Comment: Do you have yafu and/or pfgw and a fast computer ? You could help me in several factorization- and prime-finding-projects. pari/gp is of (limited) value as well.

Comment: unfortunately no, I'm using a 5-years-old laptop, almost all computations I perform (usually for own curiosity, in own investigations like this) I do with WolframAlpha, sometimes I ask my friend who has a stronger machine and a student version of Mathematica, but I don't have an access to a really powerful computer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513224/a-possible-solution-for-erdõs-conjecture-n2-1-k-and-brocards-problem

Comment: What was there under this link? This question was removed...